# Angular or Node.js inserting duplicates into Mysql on Node restart

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

My app has users entering in data like bids or posts. I noticed if I made a bid all works as intended but if the node server is closed and reopened then it duplicates the same post in MySQL. Now If I do multiple bids in one session and then close the node server it doesn't duplicate all of them but just some of them.

I noticed in my network tab there are pending requests for some of the bids I make.
Upon restarting the node server, some of these bids are duplicated here.

This is an Angular 6 app.
My educated guess is Angular or node is not fulfilling something so those pending requests upon restarting inserting the duplicated data.

Any idea to what might be causing this. Ill provide the code just incase

Here is the angular service that calls the api

```
placeBid(jobId, bidAmount: number, userId) {

const bidPayload = {
  jobId: jobId,
  userId: userId,
  bidAmount: bidAmount
};

this.http.post<{message: string}>('http://localhost:2200/api/jobs/place-bid', bidPayload).subscribe((responseData) => {
  console.log(responseData);
});
```

}

here is my node code

```
 router.post("/place-bid/", checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {


pool.query(`
SELECT contractors.cont_id
FROM users
JOIN contractors on users.user_id = contractors.user_id
WHERE users.user_id = ${req.body.userId}
`, (err, results, fields) => {
let contId = results[0].cont_id;
console.log(contId);
  pool.query(`
  SELECT jobs.cust_id
  FROM jobs
  WHERE job_id = ${req.body.jobId}
  `, (custErr, custResults, custFields) => {
    console.log('cust results: ' + custResults);
    pool.query(`
    INSERT INTO bid(job_id, cont_id, cust_id, bid_amount) VALUES (${req.body.jobId},${results[0].cont_id},${custResults[0].cust_id}, ${req.body.bidAmount})
    `, (insertErr, insertResults, insertFields) => {
      console.log('Nested Results: ' + JSON.stringify(results));
    }
  )
  })


})


  });
```

Confused to what is causing this but Ive been scratching my head the past few days.

**EDIT:** I think I have narrowed it down to the pending requests. Right now the scenario is:

Make bids/posts -> Server restart -> bids/posts duplicated

I noticed that if I:

Make bids/posts -> Refresh page (removes pending requests) -> Server restart -> No duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

My requests didn't have a response have the query was finished making the requests pending.
After adding these responses the pending is gone and there are no longer any duplicates

```
 res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Bid placed!'
  })
```